# enforced password policy 19.04

Tags: password, 19.04, policy

I am trying 19.04. All fine but it enforce a password policy. How do I turn this these suggestions off and can use my simple 1234 password?

thanks

Comment: The 1234 password is a joke, you might as well skip it, and search for a how to that disables passwords altogether.

Comment: I disagree. If you have a system that stays at your home and you got nothing special on your machine I would not care about a password too. Heck even a good difficult password is useless when people can just reboot your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That password policy is not 19.04 but was introduces years ago. At least 14.04 did it the same way. It is a feature of PAM.

Use

```
sudo nano /etc/pam.d/common-password
```

and change

```
password     [success=1 default=ignore]    pam_unix.so obscure sha512
```

to

```
password     [success=1 default=ignore]    pam_unix.so sha512 minlen=4
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Ubuntu user manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/user-management.html):

> By default, Ubuntu requires a minimum password length of 6 characters, as well as some basic entropy checks.

So you can set lenght of password to 4 characters. But then you also need to disable these entropy checks.

From `man pam_unix` (standard UNIX authentication module):

> **obscure** - enable some extra checks on password strength

So what you need to do is

in */etc/pam.d/common-password* find line:

```
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure sha512
```

and rewrite it:

```
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so sha512 minlen=4
```

You need to open *common-password* file with root privileges:

`$sudo nano /etc/pam.d/common-password`